# Simultaneous audio to headphone jack and bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio, headphone-jack

I would like to output audio both to the headphone jack and to bluetooth headphones *simultaneously*.  The purpose is for two people to listen at the same time (and we don't have a headphone splitter at hand).

Is this possible on Android phones?

The phone in question is a Samsung S5 mini with Lollipop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done.

Android can only output media to one of them at a time.

When you plug in a new device, the last one used will be overridden.